# Azure Update Management - includes Exchange and SQL updates?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

There appears to be no mention anywhere in the docs about other Microsoft apps that might be updated as part of Azure Update Management.

Will SQL and Exchange receive updates via this route? I don't expect rollup packages, but at least security updates would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Using Update Management in Azure Automation you can manage operating system updates for your Windows and Linux virtual machines or virtual machine scale sets in Azure, physical or VMs in on-premises environments, and in other cloud environments.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/overview#external-dependencies) Update management uses external dependencies to deliver there software updates.

As mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29434) , if you are using SQL server on azure VM the SQL updates are deployed through Microsoft Update (MU), so you should be able to utilize either (as long as the machine is configured to install 1st party updates).Not sure if the sql solution supports clustering. Specifically, SQL has Cumulative Updates (CUs) that get published to Microsoft Update. Then MU does automated patching.

We would suggest you to raise a request product feedback using [this](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/8ddd03a2-0225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858) link.